# React Router v4. Redirect not working

Tags: reactjs

I have application with a list and a details components. When i do redirect from the list to the details redirect working is fine. 
But when details to list it is not working. What can be wrong?

Here is details.js

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    this.setState({redirect: true});
    $.post("http://localhost:8090/api/sendSimple", {
            template: this.state.template
        },
        function (data, status) {
            if (data.code !== '0') {
                alert("Error. " + data.message);
            } else {
                alert("Success");
                this.setState({redirect: true});
            }
        }.bind(this));
};
render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
        return <Switch>
            <div>
                <Redirect push to={"/list"}/>
                <Route path="/list" component={App}/>
            </div>
        </Switch>;
    }
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';    
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
    , document.getElementById('app'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Please share detailed code snippet.

Comment: i don't see any problem in this code, it seems to work for me : https://codesandbox.io/s/lr6qyxqz0l

Answer (score 0):

Need to wrap in . Only so this work. I don't know why